# What does 大穴 mean here?

Tags: meaning, translation

> しかし......事前に聞いてはいたけど、下の名前......変わってるな。
>
> 「これ、とうわ......芸名か源氏名、通り名にリングネーム、ついでに大穴で内なる２Ｐキャラのこの世せ界で通称する為の仮名って線もありますけど」「本名なんだな、これが」

The protagonist meets his aunt for the first time in long time and she gives him  her 名刺 and he finds the name rather weird. now , what does 大穴 add here in his description of  what may be the name of here other-self (he is making fun of her name ) ?

Answer (score 4):

Typically in a horse race, 大穴 is the horse with the highest odds, i.e., the least likely to win. As such it means a *remote(st) possibility*.

Here 大穴 itself is not one of the list of possibilities. The structure is, *This name, Towa, can be (1)芸名 or (2)源氏名, (3)通り名 or (4)リングネーム, and in addition 大穴で(5)...という線もある*. The last part says literally *the remotest possibility is the lines that ...*, where *line* means like English *along those lines*. It implies that the name is strange (or the whole phrase is a joke), but not necessarily that the speaker makes fun of the name.